# Python automatically changing multiple dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I don't understand why python automatically changes dataframe. In the code below, I create the dataframe df. I then want to store the initial values in the dataframe df2. However, when I execute any operation on df, also the other dataframe df2 automatically changes. How can I avoid that?

```
# intialise data of lists.
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
        'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]}
 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 
# Define a new dataframe
df2 = df

# Multiply by 2
df.Age = df.Age*2


df2.Age # Now also this age values are doubled
```

Comment: Use [`df.copy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html). If you want to understand the current scenario in much deeper level I would recommend check out this awesome [blog](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html#h_names_and_values)

Answer (score 1):

In the line `df2 = df` it's defined that `df2` points on `df` (not creating a new one), so we get two pointers (`df` and `df2`) referencing the same dataframe.

Use the [`copy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) function to copy to a new dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

# intialise data of lists.
data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
        'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18]}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Define a new dataframe
df2 = df.copy()

# Multiply by 2
df.Age = df.Age * 2

print(df2.Age) # Now df2 unchanged
```

Output:

```
0    20
1    21
2    19
3    18
Name: Age, dtype: int64
```